# Android Push Notification clear status Bar but not notification Tray(only when screen switch off then backon)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I just have a minor issue in my push notification(Running a LG G3), when i click on the notification, it is removed from the top(the status bar) but when you scroll down from the top(it shows the notification tray), the notification is still there, but when i switch the screen off and back on, it is removed(automatically).

I attached a picture below to show where the notification that ISN'T removed.

No idea why. I want the notification to be removed as well, not just in the status bar.
I have set

```
.setAutoCancel(true);
```

[image]

Code:

```
public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
    {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String appName = getAppName(this);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        int defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

        if (extras.getString("defaults") != null) {
            try {
                defaults = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("defaults"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setDefaults(defaults)
                .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
                .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        String message = extras.getString("message");
        if (message != null) {
            mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
        }

        String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");
        if (msgcnt != null) {
            mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
        }

        int notId = 0;


        try {
            notId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("notId"));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID" + e.getMessage());
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, notId, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

I also tried to add in the part below to take out the notification. But i dont have much knowledge in Java i must say.

```
 public void onResume(boolean multitasking) {
        super.onResume(multitasking);
        gForeground = true;
 final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }
```

Comment: So you're saying you're clicking on the notification in the screen you have a screenshot of (Legal Docs?) and then it only disappears from the status bar? Also please post entire notification creation code (from builder instantiation to.buil())

Comment: The pic is just to show where the part thats not disappearing from(But yes if my notifications is received, and i clicked on it where the legal docs are, it will open the App, but when i put the app back to the background, the notification is still there, but just disappear from the status bar. I posted the code. I am actually building it for Phonegap, and i am making the alteration to the push plugin.

Comment: The odd thing is after i clicked on the notification and exit the app, i dont have to click clear(Don't have to manually clear the notification), just have to switch screen off then screen back on, then the notification in the tray will be cleared.